# Configure debug port in Jboss Fuse 6.x

Tags: jbossfuse, karaf

How to configure port for remote debugging in Configure debug port in Jboss Fuse 6.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit **$JBOSS_FUSE_HOME/bin/karaf** (%JBOSS_FUSE_HOME%/bin/karaf.bat)

---

Find line

DEFAULT_JAVA_DEBUG_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,**address=5005**"

**address=5005** sets remote debug port